# What value can be assigned to the "container" property of dx-load-panel, DevExtreme angular component?

Tags: angular, devextreme

What value can be assigned to the "container" property of dx-load-panel, DevExtreme component?

I want to dx-load-panel only to shade a component, not entire page. It looks like that I should configure the "container" property. What kind of value should I assigned to?

I am using DevExtreme v 19.2 and angular 8

Thanks.

Reference:

[https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxLoadPanel
/Configuration/#container](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxLoadPanel/Configuration/#container)

container 
Specifies the widget's container.
Type: String| DOM Node |jQuery
Default Value: undefined

The default container is defined during the widget's initialization. It is the viewport, or the body element if the viewport is not found, or the parent element if the previous two are absent.
The specified container is shaded when the LoadPanel is visible; the LoadPanel inherits styles from the container and is scrolled with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [position](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxLoadPanel/Configuration/#position) option instead. Take a look at their [LoadPanel Angular demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/LoadPanel/Overview/Angular/Light/). They pass an element id attribute there and LoadPanel "shades" only the `<div id="employee">` element.